# Connect to mysql on another device

Tags: server, php, mysql, nginx

I have two device on my network LB (`192.168.1.10`) and RP1 (`192.168.0.20`) I am wanting all the MySQL stuff to be hosted on the LB and all the web stuff to be hosted on the RP1.

I have installed `mysql-server-5.5` on both devices. But when I perform the command:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("192.168.1.10","foo","password","max");
```

On the web page I get the error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.10' (111) in /var/www/example.info/public_html/submit.php on line 6

And obviously when I try `localhost` (replacement for "192.168.1.10" in the snippet above) I get the error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'max'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /var/www/example.info/public_html/submit.php on line 6

---

I have also tried:

```
$mysql --host=192.168.1.10
```

On the RP1 and I get the error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.10' (111)

---

## What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you have to edit the file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and make the `bind-address` the ip address you would like to give access to. And if you would like all you write `0.0.0.0`